# Can't get touch event detected on a view and click event detected on a parent view

Tags: android, gesture, ontouchlistener, onclicklistener

I've got a layout 'layout_base' that fills the screen and a child view 'home'.
I set an `OnClickListener` on the 'layout_base' to do some action (close a popup if it's open), and an `OnTouchListener` on 'home' to do some other action (translate on fling).

My issue is that I can only get the action done if I return `true` in the `onTouch` method of the 'home' touch listener. If I return `false`, onFling is not called. Why? From the doc I've read that this only mean that the event is consumed, i.e. from my understanding that it is not propagated to other listener.

So:

- if I return `true` in `onTouch`, `onFling` is called, but then the onClick in the onClickListener of the parent view 'layout_base' is not called.
- if I return `false` in `onTouch`, `onFling` is not called, but then the onClick in the onClickListener of the parent view 'layout_base' is called.

How can I get both my onFling detection working on 'home', and my onClick detection working on 'layout_base'?

Thanks you

```
layout_base = findViewById(R.id.layout_base);
layout_base.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        closePopup();  // never called
    }
});     

contentGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new ContentGestureListener());
contentGestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {  
        contentGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true; // onFling only called if return true
    }
};

home.setOnTouchListener(contentGestureListener);

class ContentGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


        final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
        final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
        final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200; 

        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;

        if(e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            if(!mMenuOpen){                        
                mOpenMenuAnim.start();
                mMenuOpen = true;
            }
        }
        else if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            if(mMenuOpen){ 
                mCloseMenuAnim.start();
                mMenuOpen = false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you paste your whole activity/layout as well.

Answer (score 1):

the `onTouch()` consume the event , you should in your method `onTouch()` , return `false` instead of true

```
public boolean onTouch(View v , MotionEvent motionEvent) {
  // your code 
  return false;
}
```

**EDIT :**

change your method onTouch() like this :

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {  
        return contentGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: implement the onTouch() of your gestureDetector and return false too ,

Comment: I already implemented `onTouch()`, where should I implement it again?

Comment: in your ContentGestureListener class , and return false

Comment: `onTouch` is not a method of `SimpleOnGestureListener`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html, can you show me some code please?

Comment: With `return contentGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);`, `onFling()` is not called :(

Answer (score 0):

I have run accross the same thing.  You need to return true in the onTouch down event to receive move and up events (and make gestures work).  Then you need to implement one of the functions [talked about here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventHandlers) to make the rest work.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to

- return false in onTouch => onClick gets called
- in Home.onInterceptTouchEvent, you can return true if you detect a 'fling' (by comparing the x/y values of the incoming MOVE action)

By returning true, the events towards the layout_base will be canceled and no onClick will occur there in that case.